# Initialize view at bottom of the window in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a chat room project with React Native. So I want my latest message to be shown at the bottom and every time the page reloads, the scrollbar will initialize at the bottom, and the user can scroll from bottom to top.

I can do this by utilizing `maxHeight: 100dvh` and `flexDirection: column-reverse` with React and CSS on the web, but I can't achieve the same behaviour on the web with React Native.

Here is the React + CSS demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/chat-room-web-clxqz2?file=/src/App.tsx

Here is the React Native demo: https://snack.expo.dev/@snow_yang/chat-room

If some of you have any ideas, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll to the bottom of the `FlatList`, you can try using the method `scrollToEnd()` on the `FlatList` ref. You can call this method after the `FlatList` is rendered or when new messages are added. You can also use the prop `onContentSizeChange` to trigger the scrolling when the content size changes.

For example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const MessageView = () => {
  const messages = [...];

  const flatListRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (flatListRef.current) {
      flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: false });
    }
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.messageContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.userName}>{item._id}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.userName}>{item.user.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.messageText}>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={messages}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        onContentSizeChange={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd()}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
  },
  messageContainer: {
    padding: 10,
    marginVertical: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  userName: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  messageText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default MessageView;
```

Comment: This works fine on Android and iOS emulators.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Victor. I tried on the web, but this is not working, do you know why is that?

Comment: The `FlatList` component behaves differently on the web than on mobile platforms. The `FlatList` component inherits from the `ScrollView` component, which has some limitations and caveats on the web such as `The scroll event throttling is off by default.`

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will keep looking for the answer.